# Issue when Integrate Karate with AWS Device farm

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, gradle, karate, aws-device-farm

Trying to integrate Karate with AWS Device Farm and implement the **Target** Interface throws Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method stop(ScenarioRuntime) in Target.
Karate version: 1.2.0

Java application not compiled because of this and the build should work without this error

```
import com.intuit.karate.driver.Target;

public class DeviceFarmTarget implements Target {
 @Override
    public Map<String, Object> start(Logger logger) {
    // implementation
    }

}
```

Comment: stop() also has to be implemented as explained here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-drivertarget

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be moving from a very old version, and this part of the 1.0 upgrade guide has details: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#karate-ui

```
> if you implemented a custom Target, the method signature for start() and stop() takes a com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioRuntime as the single argument instead of a Logger.
```

I strongly suggest you move to 1.3.0 which is the latest, but yes you need to read all the release notes. If still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Yep. Using ScenarioRuntime argument instead of Logger solves the problem.